# Can access serial port with Python 2.6, but not with 2.7 or 3.5 using same code and port

Tags: python, python-2.7, port, pyserial

I am able to run scripts with Python 2.6.6 that open the serial port and exchange data bidirectionally. After installing both Python 2.7 and 3.5, needed for objects that cannot be executed in 2.6, I receive the same error (IOError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out).

I installed both 2.7 and 3.5 using (make altinstall) followed by (easy_install-2.7 -U pyserial) and (easy_install-3.5 -U pyserial).

Does anyone have a good guess as to why 2.6 will open the port and pass data, but both 2.7 and 3.5 fail?

I am running on CentOS 6.8, Kernel Linux 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 and using a USB to DB9 serial cable without any issues in 2.6.

```
python stest.py
Hello World from serial port running under Python 2.6.6.

python2.7 stest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stest.py", line 3, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',timeout=0,xonxoff=False,rtscts=False,dsrdtr=False)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/serial/serialutil.py", line 182, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 267, in open
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 588, in _update_rts_state
IOError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out


python3.5 stest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stest.py", line 3, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',timeout=0,xonxoff=False,rtscts=False,dsrdtr=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyserial-3.2.1-py3.5.egg/serial/serialutil.py", line 236, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyserial-3.2.1-py3.5.egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 288, in open
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyserial-3.2.1-py3.5.egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 605, in _update_rts_state
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

The stest.py script:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',timeout=0,xonxoff=False,rtscts=False,dsrdtr=False)
ser.write("Hello from CentOS box.");
while True:
    chunk = ser.read(128)
    if(chunk != ''):
        print(chunk + '\n')

ser.close()
```

As suggested earlier, I did try to open the port several times. I had read that may be an issue from other posts. I also increased the timeout from 0 to 5. Still no joy. Here is that version (assuming I understood the way to make the multiple attempts):

```
import serial

ser = 0

for i in range (1, 20):
    print("Attempt" + str(i))
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',timeout=5,xonxoff=False,rtscts=False,dsrdtr=False)
        if(ser):
            break
    except:
        print("Failed")


ser.write("Hello from CentOS");
while True:
    chunk = ser.read(24)
    if(chunk != ''):
        print(chunk + '\n')

ser.close()
```

I think this may be kernel related. **I was able to exchange data by changing the rtscts value from False to 1.** Unfortunately, this does not help my end goal since the remote device is 3-wire and does not support handshaking (RTS/CTS). So, I am still without a solution. The question now is:
**Why does the (rtscts value of False) fail in 2.7 and 3.5, but work in 2.6.6?**

The working code (but not usable to me because my equip does not handshake):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',timeout=0,xonxoff=False,rtscts=1,dsrdtr=False)
ser.write(b"Hello from CentOS");
while True:
  chunk = ser.read(24)
    if(chunk):
        print(str(chunk) + '\n')

ser.close()
```

Adding to the evolution of my discovery, it is indeed an issue in the **compatibility of CentOS 6.8 and pyserial's serialutil.py and serialposix.py**. I can open a serial port and read/write data just fine with rtscts = 1. If I reconfigure the port during run time and set rtscts to False, 2.6.6 handles it well. Pythons 2.7 and 3.5 immediately issue errors and abort displaying the same ([Errno 110]) error shown at the beginning of my post. Here is the code if others would care to replicate. Preferably CentOS users since this is likely OS related.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',timeout=0,xonxoff=False,rtscts=1,dsrdtr=False)

# Python 2.6.6, 2.7, and 3.5 will send this following string.
ser.write(b"Hello from CentOS");

# Python 2.7 and 3.5 error-out after this change, but system Python (2.6.6) is okay.
ser.rts = False

while True:
    chunk = ser.read(24)
    if(chunk):
        print(str(chunk) + '\n')

ser.close()
```

Any suggestions on next steps? Am I just out of luck?

Comment: did you add yourself to dial-up group ? And try : run py2.6 codes more than one time.

Comment: Yes. I am part of the dialout group. Without that access even the system Python attempt would fail. I even tried a loop that attempted the (ser=serial) line 20 times, each attempt failed for the IO error. If I try the system Python (2.6) right after that failure the port opens. The 20x loop took about 15 seconds to run. I would hope that is enough time.

Comment: `pySerial` is for serial port manipulation. How to manipulate  `USB PORT` ? `OS` can set a parameter to USB HOST.

Comment: To dsgdfg: Not sure I understand your comment. I am using pyserial successfully for serial port transfer. I am using it successfully in Python 2.6.6. I can also use the serial port successfully with minicom and the Linux command line. It is just Python2.7 and 3.5 that error out.

Comment: Py2.6 can manipulate some `OS_level_Action` but other version can't do it. Prepare with `OS` before accesing from python.  How to set serial accesing parameters on Py27-35 (to_USB_HOST)? Can't do that cos waiting a `ready for use` buss-line . When atached a device `if serial number is XXXX` do some setting to buss-line.

Comment: To dsgdfg: Thanks for the hint, but I am not sure it is a setup issue. I can use pyserial successfully on 2.7 and 3.5 to pass data bidirectionally as long as I have rts_cts = 1 upon initialization. If after passing data successfully, I issue the following: ser.rts = False (or None or 0), I get an immediate  timeout error and Python aborts. Does your preparation suggestion have to occur before each use of serial.Serial ?